# center an inline unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

For an assignment, I've created an inline "unordered list" with multiple list items (which are to be my social links). I've also removed the bullet point from each 'li' item.

However, I can't get the list to center align. It seems to be pushed to the right by a handful of pixels.

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/RayanJ/pen/KpPmJg)

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
    <header class="headerstyle1">
        <nav>
        <a href="#" title="Contact Me" ="#" class="button2">Contact</a>
        <a href="#" title="Résumé" class="button1">Résumé</a>
        <a href="#" title="About Me" class="button1">About Me</a>
    </nav>
        <div class="ninesixty">
            <h1>Rayan Jawad</h1>
            <h2>Data Marketer // Growth Hacker</h2>

            <ul class="sociallist">
                <li><a href="#" title = "Facebook">             FB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title = "Twitter">              TW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title = "Google Plus">          GP  </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title = "Linkedin">LI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title = "Skype">                SK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title = "Instagram">        IG</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:#" title = "Email Me">EM                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: reset padding to 0 on <ul> :)  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqKjVx

Answer (score 0):

use text-align:center;

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<!--Font Awesome - for Social Media Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--Google Font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />



<title>Rayan Jawad</title>
```

```
<!-- Top Part of the Page -->
<header class="headerstyle1">
<nav>
    <a href="#" title="Contact Me" ="#" class="button2">Contact</a>
    <a href="#" title="Résumé" class="button1">Résumé</a>
    <a href="#" title="About Me" class="button1">About Me</a>
</nav>
    <div class="ninesixty">
        <h1>Rayan Jawad</h1>
        <h2>Data Marketer // Growth Hacker</h2>

        <ul class="sociallist">
            <li style=" text-align: center;"><a href="#" title = "Facebook">             FB</a></li>
            <li style=" text-align: center;"><a href="#" title = "Twitter">              TW</a></li>
            <li style=" text-align: center;"><a href="#" title = "Google Plus">          GP  </a></li>
            <li style=" text-align: center;"><a href="#" title = "Linkedin">LI</a></li>
            <li style=" text-align: center;"><a href="#" title = "Skype">                SK</a></li>
            <li style=" text-align: center;"><a href="#" title = "Instagram">        IG</a></li>
            <li style=" text-align: center;"><a href="mailto:#" title = "Email Me">EM                </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</header>
```

Comment: then what do you want?